# Misunderstanding about the concept of uniform convergence in an unbounded set

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

It may sound as a stupid question but I want to have everything clear about this concept: given a series of functions $\sum f_n(x)$ that converges uniformly in $[0,a] \ \forall a\geq0$, can we claim that the series converges uniformly in $[0,+\infty[$? If so, why?

Comment: Some searching on this site will provide many examples where a series converges uniformly on a finite interval $[0,a]$ for every $a > 0$, but not on $[0,\infty)$. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3369912/148510) is one.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot say that. As long as you have a finite interval, you can wait for convergence to be uniform over the whole interval. If you have an infinite interval, you might always be able to go out sufficiently far that the convergence is still at least $1$ unit away.

Look at the series for $$e^x=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$ For any interval $[0,a]$, the slowest convergence is at $x=a$, so you can wait until it converges sufficiently at $x=a$. However, if you have the interval $[0,+\infty[$, the convergence is not uniform as every partial sum is a polynomial. Given any polynomial $P(x)$, there will always be an $x_0>0$ so that $|e^x-P(x_0)|>1$.

Comment: @SineoftheTime It converges absolutely everywhere (pointwise) but as Aaron showed that doesn't imply uniform convergence on $\mathbb{R}$.